# Java: Safe way to copy/move files from one directory to another

Tags: java, file, java-io

We have a system where we are dealing with file operations, and in my case i would have to copy or move file(s) from one directory to another. Could anybody let me know a safe way to do this? For instance: lets say during the copy or move execution, if the system reboots, how do i ensure my operation executes gracefully. An example snippet would be very helpful.

Comment: Your program could keep a private log of which files have been copied and which still need to be copied, so it could resume that operation later.

Comment: @VGR- thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this way:

```
File fileFrom= new File("/FileDirectory");
Path FROM = Paths.get(fileFrom.getPath());
File fileTo= new File("/FileDirectory");
Path TO = Paths.get(fileTo.getPath());

        //sobreescribir el fichero de destino, si existe, y copiar los atributos, incluyendo los permisos rwx
        CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
            StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
            StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
        };
        try {
            Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error1: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error2: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: a) Why exactly are you mixing java.io.File and java.nio.Path?
b) Why are you putting the path as String into a File, just to then get it out of the File again?

Comment: This does not address the question, which is asking how to resume a copy or move operation after a reboot.